# How to retrieve the name of a system call in xv6?

Tags: system-calls, xv6

Is there a way to retrieve the name of a system call being made while in syscall()? I see that we have access to the number; can I use that somehow?

Answer (score 5):

if you want a string you have to hold an array of syscall names.
you can do it in `syscall.c` just like `syscalls[]`:

```
static char* syscallnames[] = {
[SYS_fork]    "fork",
[SYS_exit]    "exit",
[SYS_wait]    "wait",
...
};
```

and use it in `syscall()` like this:

```
void
syscall(void)
{
  int num;

  num = proc->tf->eax;
  if(num > 0 && num < NELEM(syscalls) && syscalls[num]) {
    cprintf("calling sys call: %s", syscallnames[num]); // <<< code addition
    proc->tf->eax = syscalls[num]();
  } else {
    cprintf("%d %s: unknown sys call %d\n",
            proc->pid, proc->name, num);
    proc->tf->eax = -1;
  }
}
```